# divs not filling white-space in display: table;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a slideshow and to the right of it there are divs, they will be enlarged when you hover over them and when you take your cursor off the div it will shrink. But, the aside (the divs parent) is in the correct place where it should be, it's the divs that aren't filling the top of the aside element. How can I get the divs to fill the aside element and not break anything else?

```css
.thing {
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
.thing:hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
.report {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.aside {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 385px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="report">
  <div id="imgGallary" class="container">
    <img src="images/companies.png" alt="" width="750" height="400" />
    <img src="gallery" alt="" width="750" height="400" />
  </div>
  <aside class="aside">
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div class="thing" style="background-color: blue;">
      <h1>Find Us!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="thing" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
    <div class="thing" style="background-color: pink"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me as you described. I am testing in FF. What browsers are you testing in?

Comment: It's working for me as well, in Chrome for OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS layout is confusing `display: table` and `display: relative`. They aren't compatible like you have them. The preferred way to layout your `.container` and the `aside` would be to use f[loats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). I revised your example to float those two containers next to each other (roughly at a 80/20 split for the width). This has the added bonus of making your layout responsive.

Working codepen:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/vKoPmw

```
.thing {
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid brown;
}
.thing:hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.report {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.aside {
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 18%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1% solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 385px;
}
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```